# How to create single image from cell array of matrices in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, cell

I needed to split a grayscale image in equal parts so I used the function `mat2cell`. Then I had to equalize each of the parts separatelly, for this purpose I used the function `histeq`. I reused the same cell array variable for this. Here is the code:

```
height=round(size(img,1)/number_of_divisions);
length=round(size(img,2)/number_of_divisions);
M=zeros(number_of_divisions,1);
N=zeros(1,number_of_divisions);
M(1:number_of_divisions)=height;
N(1:number_of_divisions)=length;
aux=mat2cell(img,M,N);

for i=1:size(aux,1)
    for j=1:size(aux,2)
        aux{i,j}=histeq(aux{i,j},256);
    end
end
```

So now how do I merge each cell into one single image?

Comment: Just noticed your first tow lines don't work always. For size `[1001,1001]` and `number_of_divisions` it fails. Another reason to use `blockproc`

Comment: yeah that's true, thanks. I've been trying to discover it by myself but I still don't understand what `blockproc` does with the pixels that wouldn't be "taken" when the division of pixels by number of blocks isn't an integer (the reason it doesn't work as well with mat2cell). Could you explain me please?

Comment: `blockproc` uses the size you pass and the last row / column of blocks is smaller if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cell2mat`

```
img2=cell2mat(aux);
```

For a better performance, replace your code with `blockproc`

```
blocksize=ceil(size(img)./number_of_divisions);
img2=blockproc(img,blocksize,@(block_struct)histeq(block_struct.data));
```

Comment: Yeah It worked! I should have guessed, matlab has a function for every problem :D